# confused on fitting matrix or tf_idf

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-fitting

So I have this dataframe **df**:

```
index
0       horse horse horse Horse Rboe
1       area Build extra ice line located Metro Overpass overpass passes track track viaduct work
2       Better Crane Overpass site view work
3       bench BUrdock dirt flower maniacs PATH southeast southeast southeast spring walk
4       Bank beach meSH mesh mesh puddle puddle puddle south southeast southeast
```

and I wanted to cluster them with k-means. So I vectorize it first with TfidfVectorizer like this:

```
vec = TfidfVectorizer(
      lowercase = True,
      stop_words = 'english',
      use_idf=True
 )

matrix = vec.fit_transform(df)
```

So far I have this term-document **matrix** and I turned it to dataframe **idf_df**:

```
idf_df = pd.DataFrame(matrix.toarray(), columns=vec.get_feature_names())
```

[image]

Now before I want to cluster them with K-Means, I need to look at the optimum **k-cluster** first using the **KElbowVisualizer**:

```
model = MiniBatchKMeans(MiniBatchKMeans(init_size=1024, batch_size=2048, random_state=20).fit(matrix).inertia_)
visualizer = KElbowVisualizer(model,k=(2, 560), metric='silhouette', timings=False, size=(4080, 3720))
visualizer.fit(matrix)        # Fit the data to the visualizer
```

But I'm confused **what argument** to insert in the function **fit()**??

should I insert **idf_df**? but that does not make sense as it is dataframe. But when I insert **matrix** instead, the cluster would not make sense.

Can someone please help me to understand this?

Comment: Why would the same data being a dataframe vs an array make a difference? The only real change is adding column headers. Your question could use some clarification.

Comment: @G.Anderson I'm also wondering that, because I apply both **matrix** and **idf_df** to 560 rows of a dataframe and it shows different results

Comment: That would be good detail to [edit] into your question, if that's the main point that is confusing you. Show how you applied it, and how the output is different